# Node.js multidimensional object and dynamic variable names

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am experimenting with node.js socket.io and different rooms. I have nicknames object with all users that are connected, but the problem is in this object I cannot store duplicate values for user Ids, thus I cannot make the same user to use different rooms. Now, I would like to make different object for each rooms instead this nicknames object for all users. So how can I do something like this: nicknames[specific_room][user.id]=rest of the code.. ? So, then I should have separate list of data for each room? Or should I use dynamic variable names for each separate room? What can you suggest?

```
  nicknames[user.id]={

        'nickname': user.name,
        'socketId': socket.id,
        'room': room,
};
```

the result:

```
    { '1':
       { nickname: 'User1',
         socketId: '/#0rb7zbg0RInwKAaMAAAC',
         room: '4444',
       }, 
      '3':
       { nickname: 'User 2',
         socketId: '/#tGZPL8IUPvUoie1CAAAD',
         room: '3333',
        } 
}
```

What would I like to accomplish:

```
    { 3333 {     { '1':
               { nickname: 'User1',
                 socketId: '/#0rb7zbg0RInwKAaMAAAC',

                },
              '3':
               { nickname: 'User 2',
                 socketId: '/#tGZPL8IUPvUoie1CAAAD',

                } 
        }
    }

    4444 {
    }
}
```

where 3333 and 4444 are the room unique IDs.
I hope I made it clear.

Comment: There is something like `socket.join(room_id_here)` and `socket.leave(room_id_here)`. Join will add the user to the room ID that is given in and leave will remove the user from that room. I'm experimenting with NodeJS and socket.io too :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not experienced with socket.io but you could easily do something like this with plain javascript (probably not the most elegant solution, but it works fine):

```
var obj = { 
  '1': { 
    nickname: 'User1',
    socketId: '/#0rb7zbg0RInwKAaMAAAC',
    room: '4444',
   }, 
  '3': { 
    nickname: 'User 2',
    socketId: '/#tGZPL8IUPvUoie1CAAAD',
    room: '3333',
  } 
};

var obj2 =  {};


for(var i in obj) {
  obj2[obj[i].room] = {};
  obj2[obj[i].room][i] = { 
    nickname: obj[i].nickname, 
    socketId: obj[i].socketId 
  };
}

console.log(obj2);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x7bom3b/)